# Cannot Connect to Flash Media Server on Linux VPS CentOS Server with Flash Media Live Encoder

Tags: linux, flash, adobe, flash-media-server, fmle

I am trying to setup a live HTTP stream using Flash Media Live Encoder and Flash Media Server 4.0, and I am getting connection errors each and every single time I try to connect, though I am doing everything (as far as I can tell) by the book. I have my FMS server installed (and verified as running) on my Linux CentOS Virtual Private Server, ports 80 and 1935 open, I have the following liveevent.xml file uploaded and where it needs to be in it's own folder on the server installation folder /opt/adobe/applications/livepkgr/*definst*/liveevent/:

```
<Event> 
  <EventID>liveevent</EventID> 
  <Recording> 
    <FragmentDuration>4000</FragmentDuration> 
    <SegmentDuration>16000</SegmentDuration> 
    <DiskManagementDuration>3</DiskManagementDuration> 
  </Recording> 
</Event>
```

My encoder FMS Url: rtmp://:1935/livepkgr

and my Stream: liveevent?adbe-live-event=liveevent

I get the error: "Problem With Primary Server. Failure to connect to primary server. Please verify that your server URl and application name are valid and that your internet connection is working and retry."

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your rtmp URL misses the domain. It should look like

```
rtmp://SOMEDOMAIN.TLD:1935/livepkgr
```

Comment: appears not to be it either.